# conditional redirection doesn't work

Tags: php, redirect

```
$("#btnok").click(function(){
var pass = $('#inputpass').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'passpro.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'pass': pass},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#info').text(data);
    }
});
});
```

The above works fine. Now I want to redirect to `index.php` if password exists, and echo a message if it doesn't.

**passpro.php**

```
include ("params.php");
include ("$config");

$pass = $_POST['pass'];

try {
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM passwords WHERE pass = :pass');
$stmt->execute(array(
':pass' => $pass
));

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    header("Location: index.php"); // this line doesn't work
    exit();
}
else{
    echo ('UNKNOWN PASSWORD');
}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

If `rowCount == 0` this works fine, i.e. I got the message `UNKNOWN PASSWORD`, but if `rowCount > 0` instead of redirection what I got is - html code of `index.php` written inside `#info` div !

Comment: You cannot use a php `header()` redirect like that when you make an ajax call. Instead you need to return a result (json?) and do a redirect in javascript based on that.

Comment: Using a header does nothing in AJAX requests,  you need to use JS code to reset the location.href instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Passpro.php**

```
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    return 'true'
}
else{
    echo ('UNKNOWN PASSWORD');
}
```

**Main Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'passpro.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'pass': pass},
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == 'true')
        {
            window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; //or whatever
        }
    }
});
```

I've not put an explanation because those who commented on your question have already explained